# Writing a method to add a String collection in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

So I have this data

```
Key      Value
---      -----
fruit    apple
fruit    banana
fruit    grapes

cars     honda
cars     lexus
cars     bmw

schools  harvard
schools  yale
...
```

And I would like to construct the data to a `Map<String, Collections<String>>` and make a method that adds all the data. So far, I have a constructor that instantiates my Map variable

```
public Map<String, Collection<String>> keys;

public newMap() {
    keys = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addkeys(String K, String V) {
    Collection<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    if (keys.containsKey(K) && !keys.values().contains(V)) {
        names.add(V);
        courses.put(K, names);

    } else if (!keys.containsKey(K) && !keys.values().contains(V)) {
        names.add(V);
        courses.put(student, classes);
    }
}
```

So when I run my test

```
newMap.addkeys("fruit", "apple");
newMap.addkeys("fruit, "banana");
newMap.addkeys("fruit", "grapes");
newMap.addkeys("cars, "honda");
newMap.addkeys("cars", "lexus");
newMap.addkeys("cars, "bmw");
newMap.addkeys("schools", "harvard");
newMap.addkeys("schools, "yale");
```

it should return

```
fruit = [apple, banana, grapes] 
cars = [honda, lexus, bmw]
schools = [hardvard, yale]
```

but instead I get

```
fruit = [grapes]
cars = [bmw]
schools = [yale]
```

it seems like it's only adding the last instance because whenever I call `Collection<String> names = new HashSet<String>()`, i'm re-instantiating `names` but when I this instantiation to the begininng of the class, It just adds on everything. So it returns `fruit = [apple, banana, grapes, honda, lexus, bmw, hardvard, yale]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-Java 8:

Use the fact that [`Map#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) returns `null` when there is not a mapping in order to determine if you need to `put` a new collection in the map, then add the value to the collection.

```
public void addkeys(String K, String V) {
    Collection<String> values = keys.get(K);
    if (values == null) {
        values = new HashSet<>();
        keys.put(K, values);
    }
    values.add(V);
}
```

Java 8+:

Use [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to add a new collection to the map if there is not a mapping, and then add the value to the returned collection.

```
public void addkeys(String K, String V) {
    keys.computeIfAbsent(K, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(V);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function like this:

```
public void addkeys(String K, String V) {
    if (keys.containsKey(K)) {
        keys.get(K).add(V); // add to existing hashset
    } else {
        Collection<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        names.add(V);
        keys.put(K, names); // add new hashset for key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> myMap;

public newMap() {
    myMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public void putInMap(String key, String val) {

    if (myMap.containsKey(key)) {
        myMap.get(K).add(V);
    } else {
        Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
        values.add(val);
        myMap.put(key, values);
    }
}
```